# try to create an event with cursor in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to create an event with a cursor. But getting an error below

Error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Code :

```
create event api_5 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 360 SECOND DO
BEGIN
DECLARE lc_current_time DATETIME;
DECLARE unuse_count INT;
DECLARE auto_assign TINYINT;
DECLARE total_sum INT;
DECLARE check_count INT;
SET lc_current_time = CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+0:00');

DECLARE select_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT unuse_count,auto_assign,total_sum,check_count from new_api;

OPEN select_cursor;
LOOP
     FETCH select_cursor INTO unuse_count,auto_assign,total_sum,check_count
     if(unuse_count <= check_count){
        insert into api_report(date,new_api_id,api_name,type,status,email,customer_id,unuse_count,check_count) values (lc_current_time,5,'abc',4,1,'abc@gmail.com',check_count,unuse_count);
        }
     END;
END LOOP;
CLOSE select_cursor;
END;
```

Anyone would like to suggest why it's showing on the third line. There are limitations like we can't variable multiple times.
I am trying this first time. So please ignore any mistakes.

Note : Insert query and select query both are working fine.

Second Error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE select_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT unuse_count,auto_assign,total_sum,check_' at line 10
```

Comment: Did you define a `delimiter`?

Comment: I thought if we directly execute query from command line.then there is no need of delimiter.Isn't it ?

Comment: I just added delimeter and got next issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer :

**Fixes :**

1. The delimiter is not added. which gives first error so have added delimiter in a start and at the end.
2. Without complete, all variable declaration have started to use it.
   In answer i put `SET lc_current_time = CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+0:00');` after cursor.
3. `If condition` not added as per mysql syntax

**Working Solution :**

```
delimiter $$
create event api_6 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 360 SECOND DO
BEGIN
DECLARE lc_current_time DATETIME;
DECLARE unuse_count INT;
DECLARE auto_assign TINYINT;
DECLARE total_sum INT;
DECLARE check_count INT;
DECLARE select_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT unuse_count,auto_assign,total_sum,check_count from new_api;
SET lc_current_time = CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+0:00');
OPEN select_cursor;
LOOP
     FETCH select_cursor INTO unuse_count,auto_assign,total_sum,check_count;
        IF unuse_count <= check_count THEN
          insert into api_report(date,new_api_id,api_name,type,status,email,customer_id,unuse_count,check_count) values (lc_current_time,5,'abc',4,1,'abc@gmail.com',check_count,unuse_count);
        END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE select_cursor;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: @PaulSpiegel : I just added information in answer in answer.Please confirm.

Comment: Down voters,Share reason for downvote.Instead of directly doing.So people can learn and move forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not used the delimiter, then try This might help you:

```
delimiter $$
create event api_5 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 360 SECOND DO
BEGIN
DECLARE lc_current_time DATETIME;
DECLARE unuse_count INT;
DECLARE auto_assign TINYINT;
DECLARE total_sum INT;
DECLARE check_count INT;
SET lc_current_time = CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+0:00');

DECLARE select_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT unuse_count,auto_assign,total_sum,check_count from new_api;

OPEN select_cursor;
LOOP
     FETCH select_cursor INTO unuse_count,auto_assign,total_sum,check_count
     if(unuse_count <= check_count){
        insert into api_report(date,new_api_id,api_name,type,status,email,customer_id,unuse_count,check_count) values (lc_current_time,5,'abc',4,1,'abc@gmail.com',check_count,unuse_count);
        }
     END;
END LOOP;
CLOSE select_cursor;
END
delimiter ;
```